# What is the math behind high FM frequency components being more noise prone?

Tags: signal-theory, signal-to-noise, noise-spectral-density

what is the math behind the phenomena that higher frequencies are more prone to noise?

The use of pre-emphasis to boost the higher frequency components to get a better S/N ratio.

Can you provide the math behind why the higher frequency components are more prone to noise?

Thanks!

Comment: Pre-emphasis  is the boosting of (usually) higher frequency components of a signal to compensate for attenuation in systems where higher frequencies experience higher attenuation.  It is a compensation for the limitations of the transmission medium.

Comment: A high frequency is just what it is, (a high frequency) and is not prone to noise because, in the event of noise, it remains.... a high frequency signal (of the same amplitude). You might care to describe in detail what you mean.

Comment: There's more Hz per octave at high frequencies, and white noise is equal energy per unit bandwidth (Hz),  which translates to more noise at higher frequencies simply because of the higher bandwidth. @user1850479 preemphasis is often used on channels with an otherwise very flat frequency response, including FM radio and as an option on Compact Disc.

Comment: Joe, you need to tell us what kind of system you're referring to. Your statement "higher frequencies are more prone to noise" is plain wrong like this. Background, please!

Comment: @BrianDrummond, thanks for your response!  I like your answer. Is there any reference material that you can point me to that I can refer to in relation to your answer?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I am looking at the audio spectrum (~300 - 3kHz). I was looking at pre-emphasis and read that filter is used to "boost" higher frequency signals prior to transmission as the higher frequencies tend to be noisy compared to lower frequency components in the FM system.

Comment: So, **FM** is the significant info here! You need to **edit** your question to include that, otherwise all this makes no sense.

Comment: @Joe that edit really wasn't sufficient. You need to explain what you want to transmit (audio) over what (FM, you added that only vaguely to the title) and where the frequency that are bad are (in your audio signal, not in the RF carrier frequency). We already spent 10× the textual efforts in these comments than you did on your question text – that should be the other way around.

Comment: _"I am looking at the audio spectrum (~300 - 3kHz). I was looking at pre-emphasis and read that filter is used to "boost" higher frequency signals prior to transmission"_ - Where did you read this? Can you provide an example of audio pre-emphasis in NBFM transmissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a radio communication system the ratio of received power \$P_r\$ to transmit power \$P_t\$ is given by Friis transmission equation

$$\frac{P_r}{P_t} = \frac{A_r A_t \lambda^2}{(4\pi d)^2},$$

where \$A_r\$ is the receive antenna gain, \$A_t\$ is the transmit antenna gain, \$d\$ is the distance between the antennas, and \$\lambda\$ is the wavelength. The wavelength is related to the frequency by \$\lambda = c / f\$. Hence

$$\frac{P_r}{P_t} = \frac{A_r A_t c^2}{(4\pi d)^2 f^2}.$$

Thus the higher frequencies will be attenuated more than the lower frequencies. Usually this is not a problem when the bandwidth is low compared to the carrier frequency. It can become a problem, if the bandwidth is large. The difference at 100 MHz with 200 kHz bandwidth is 0.4%.

---

Another source of the same effect is the FM demodulator. The FM demodulator consists of a differentiator and an envelope detector.

[image: FM Demodulator]

[source](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/analog_communication/analog_communication_fm_demodulators.htm)

The output of the envelope detector is

$$A[\omega_c + k_f m(t)],$$

where \$m(t)\$ is the message. An FM system is non-linear, but for high SNR it can be shown it is approximately linear. Hence the noise is amplified by the differentiator, since the transfer function is

$$H(f) = 2\pi j f.$$

Thus the noise is increased at higher frequencies.

Comment: That is right, but irrelevant to the question OP posted – within the pretty narrow bandwidth of a typical FM-modulated signal, wavelengths don't differ sufficiently enough for this to be relevant. Also, preemphasis has little to do with the RF-frequencies resulting from modulation (it works on the audio signal, not on the RF signal), so this is actually not only irrelevant, but misleading.

Comment: @MarcusMüller That’s a fair point. See my edit.

Answer (score -1):

from what I remember, the early phonograph records used shellac as the material.

The boundaries od shellac particles serve as impulses, a high frequency energy event.

Thus using a low-pass filter after playback was beneficial.

Comment: The question is about the mathematics of noise and pre-emphasis. You havren't answered or even addressed either.